# Why does restarting a computer wreak havoc on Java Build Path?

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

I'm sure we've all been there, I've got a JSF (Java) project on Eclipse that built fine yesterday, I call it quits for the night, turn off my computer and come back to it the next day only to find missing JAR errors, some of which are due to actual missing classes, others I can clearly find by navigating my build path. What's up with that? Is windows scheming against me and re-indexing files or something while I'm away?

Comment: Dumb question but by 'turn off' do you mean a hard shut down ? Do you close eclipse before shutting down the PC (whichever way you want) ?

I have similar (known) issues with my setup but that's specific to using Ivy to manage dependencies.

Comment: I close eclipse and let it save everything it needs to before turning shutting down the comp

Comment: Were the missing jars 3rd party jars, build by your, or part of the jdk? had you installed/uninstalled/updated any programs since the last time your shutdown?

Comment: no changes, the jars are mostly if not all 3rd party that I downloaded and have on local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might be IDE dependent on Eclipse Java EE Juno but on restart it created a copy of my src folder as a library which caused some Hibernate - duplicate mapping errors